# hazelcast start error Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE on linux

Tags: redhat, hazelcast, configure

How to start hazelcast when try configuring on redhat linux `systemctl status hazelcast.service` i found error `cannot find main class`  and cannot find any documentation please help. Thank  you

Comment: Could you add more details about your environment and steps on how you have installed the Hazelcast?

Comment: Setup hazelcast service at /etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service  Get and store on /opt/hazelcast/user-lib/   (attached)
- log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
- log4j-api-2.17.1.jar    
- bucket4j-core-7.2.0.jar
- bucket4j-hazelcast-3-7.2.0.ja

Comment: Have you followed the RPM installation steps in https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/getting-started/install-hazelcast#using-a-package-manager ?

Comment: yeah but that is latest one cannot find RPM for 3.12.12 version

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it's obvious you want to run the old Hazelcast IMDG version 3.12.12. This version is not supported by native package managers (as [the 5.1 is](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/getting-started/install-hazelcast#using-a-package-manager)).

Still, you can install this old Hazelcast as a standalone app and configure the systemd service on your own. See this example repository: https://github.com/kwart/hazelcast-linux-service/tree/3.12.z/

These would be the steps on RHEL (run them as `root`):

```bash
# Prerequisities
dnf install -y wget curl unzip git rsync java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless

# Clone the repo (with 3.12.z branch)
git clone -b 3.12.z https://github.com/kwart/hazelcast-linux-service.git
cd hazelcast-linux-service

# Create the hazelcast user/group
groupadd -r hazelcast
useradd -r -g hazelcast -d /opt/hazelcast -s /sbin/nologin hazelcast

# Install Hazelcast
HAZELCAST_VERSION=3.12.12
wget https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/releases/download/v$HAZELCAST_VERSION/hazelcast-$HAZELCAST_VERSION.zip
unzip hazelcast-$HAZELCAST_VERSION.zip -d /opt
ln -s /opt/hazelcast-$HAZELCAST_VERSION /opt/hazelcast
# Change owner of the Hazelcast directories and links
chown -R hazelcast:hazelcast /opt/hazelcast /opt/hazelcast-$HAZELCAST_VERSION

# Copy service and config files
rsync -r etc/ /etc

# Start and enable service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start hazelcast.service
systemctl enable hazelcast.service
```

**Warning:** *Hazelcast 3.12.z already [reached the end of the standard support](https://support.hazelcast.com/s/article/Version-Support-Windows). It's highly recommended to use an up-to-date version.*